# .Net Maui Firebase Push Notifications handling of notifications when App is closed/background

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui, maui-android

My main issue is trying to handle or intercept the Notification/Data from the push notification when the application is closed or in the background. I am aware that the OnMessageReceived from the FirebaseMessagingService won't trigger depending on what payloads you are sending.

I want to be able to send a Notification + Data payload to the application and handle the data coming in accordingly. I have read something about when the Notification is clicked it can trigger the OnNewIntent from the MainActivity.cs however, nothing seems to trigger it.

Keep in mind this is purely for .Net Maui Android.

I have tried sending just Notification Payloads, just Data payloads and both however, no matter what clicking the push notification resulted in the OnNewIntent() not being triggered at all.

In some cases I have noticed that when the App is completely closed I don't receive the push notifications always even after waiting a couple of minutes 2-5 mins.

I have tried send from my server purely push notifications using firebase plugins as well as using Azure Notifications hub however, they both seem to produce the same results.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated and can provide code on segments if more clarification is required.

Comment: Can you receive notifications when the app is closed or in the background?